# How can I include a mixin that contains a variable, then change that variables value inside a parent combinator?

Tags: css, variables, sass, mixins, scss-mixins

**UPDATE: [working CodePen](https://codepen.io/jreynolds13/pen/ZwJQep) with css variable solution.**

**UPDATE: [CSS-Tricks explains](https://css-tricks.com/difference-between-types-of-css-variables/#article-header-id-2) that css variables cascade, and the browser repaints when they change. Preprocessor variables don't have these features.**

Difficult to put this in clear terms... is it possible in Sass to overwrite a global variable with a local variable after said global variable has been included via a mixin?

I.e.: I'm looking to set a default value for a global variable `$color`, and set values for specific color variables like `$red: red;` and `$blue: blue;`. Then use global `$color` inside a mixin, then `@include` that mixin inside `.class {}`, then overwrite the value of global `$color` with local variables inside parent combinators like `.class { &.one { $color: $red; } &.two { $color: $blue; }}`

The original value of global `$color` is rendering, rather than changing to the values of the local variables. I researched `!default` and `!global` but didn't find much that helped in my case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds a job for CSS variable:

```
body {
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

$color: #000000;
$blue: #0087ff;
$red: #ff2828;
$yellow: #ffe607;

@mixin item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 1rem 1rem 0;
  width: 8rem;
  height: 8rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: var(--c,$color);
}

@mixin circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.item {
  @include item;

  &.one {
    --c: #{$blue};
  }

  &.two {
    --c: #{$red};
    @include circle;
  }

  &.three {
    --c: #{$yellow};
    @include circle;
  }
}
```

Full compiled code:

```css
body {
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 1rem 1rem 0;
  width: 8rem;
  height: 8rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: var(--c, #000000);
}
.item.one {
  --c: #0087ff;
}
.item.two {
  --c: #ff2828;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.item.three {
  --c: #ffe607;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="item one"></div> <!-- blue square -->
  <div class="item two"></div> <!-- red circle -->
  <div class="item three"></div> <!-- yellow circle -->
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks @temani-afif, this works. Curious why a css var works but not an Sass var, I'll keep researching the two. In my use case I'm fine with using a css variable. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it doesn't work because the moment your define `background-color` the value of `$color` was black so all shapes are black. In the next step the compiler reads the new value of `$color` in different child classes but this values were never reasigned to `background-color`. It would work if you reassign it like so:

```
body {
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

$color: #000000;
$blue: #0087ff;
$red: #ff2828;
$yellow: #ffe607;

@mixin item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 1rem 1rem 0;
  width: 8rem;
  height: 8rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: $color;
}

@mixin circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.item {
  @include item;
  background-color:$color;

  &.one {
    $color: $blue ;
    background-color: $color;
  }

  &.two {
    $color: $red;
    background-color: $color;
    @include circle;
  }

  &.three {
    $color: $yellow;
    background-color: $color;
    @include circle;
  }
}
```

or do it like Temani

Comment: Thanks for the pure Sass solution, @linh. I'll use the css var solution from Temani since in your example, using `$color: $blue; background-color: $color;` in a class isn't more DRY than just using `background-color: $blue` in the class. Thanks!